# double > string > double conversion

Tags: c++, stl, double

To transport data over the network I convert a double to string , send it and on the receiver side convert it back to double. 
so far so good.
But I stumbled over some weird behaviour which I'm not able to explain

The whole example code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/qggACmKt).
what i do:
Write a double to string via `ostringstream`, afterwards read it in with `istringstream`
the value changes
But if i use the function "strtod(...) " it works. (with the same `outstring`)

Example (the whole code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/qggACmKt)):

```
double d0 = 0.0070000000000000001;
out << d0;

std::istringstream in (out.str());
in.precision(Prec);
double d0X_ = strtod(test1.c_str(),NULL);

in >> d0_;
assert(d0 == d0X_); // this is ok
assert(d0 == d0_);   //this fails
```

I wonder why this happens.

The question is: "Why is 'istream >>' leading to another resulst as 'strtod'"
Please don't answer the question why IEEE 754 is no exact.

Comment: You don't show where you get "test1" from.

Comment: Nor do you show what `Prec` is set to.

Comment: Also, it's a bit late to set Prec when reading in but not when writing out. Also, -1 for terrible too many question marks, and caps.

Comment: `0.0070000000000000001` is NOT representable as a fraction in the form of x/pow(2,y), and therefore is a non-terminating number when represented in binary format.  That means it cannot be represented in a finite number of binary digits.

Comment: I ran this code using VS2010 and I get `d0_=0.0070000000000000010`, `d0x_=0.0070000000000000001` where `test1="0.0070000000000000001"` and `in="0.0070000000000000001    0.007000..."`. So, maybe there's a bug in `operator>>`

Comment: The code in the pastebin works for me on Fedora 11 with GCC 4.4.1 (also ICC 12.1, and Clang from SVN though I expect those use the same libs.)

Comment: Moreover, the literal in the first line may already exceed the precision of a IEEE 64-bit float (I'm not entirely sure, it's borderline), so you might already be feeding the problem a different value than you think you do.

Comment: the values I receive
`d0  =0.0070000000000000001` 
`d0X_=0.0070000000000000001` 
`d0_ =0.0070000000000000010`

@Skizz thanks for testing it
@Boojum thanks for testing it on GCC
I think I go with this problem to the MSDN forums it lookls like a MS problem

Answer (score 2):

**Why are they might be different:**
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.16

> Floating point is an approximation...

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17

> The reason floating point will surprise you is that float and double
>   values are normally represented using a finite precision binary
>   format. In other words, floating point numbers are not real numbers.
>   For example, in your machine's floating point format it might be
>   impossible to exactly represent the number 0.1. By way of analogy,
>   it's impossible to exactly represent the number one third in decimal
>   format (unless you use an infinite number of digits)....
>   The message is that some floating point numbers cannot always be
>   represented exactly, so comparisons don't always do what you'd like
>   them to do. In other words, if the computer actually multiplies 10.0
>   by 1.0/10.0, it might not exactly get 1.0 back.

**How to compare floating point:**
http://c-faq.com/fp/strangefp.html

> ...some machines have more precision available in floating-point
>   computation registers than in double values stored in memory, which
>   can lead to floating-point inequalities when it would seem that two
>   values just have to be equal.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17
Here's the wrong way to do it:

```
 void dubious(double x, double y)
 {
   ...
   if (x == y)  // Dubious!
     foo();
   ...
 }
```

If what you really want is to make sure they're "very close" to each other (e.g., if variable a contains the value 1.0 / 10.0 and you want to see if (10*a == 1)), you'll probably want to do something fancier than the above:

```
 void smarter(double x, double y)
 {
   ...
   if (isEqual(x, y))  // Smarter!
     foo();
   ...
 }
```

There are many ways to define the isEqual() function, including:

```
 #include <cmath>  /* for std::abs(double) */

 inline bool isEqual(double x, double y)
 {
   const double epsilon = /* some small number such as 1e-5 */;
   return std::abs(x - y) <= epsilon * std::abs(x);
   // see Knuth section 4.2.2 pages 217-218
 }
```

Note: the above solution is not completely symmetric, meaning it is possible for isEqual(x,y) != isEqual(y,x). From a practical standpoint, does not usually occur when the magnitudes of x and y are significantly larger than epsilon, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was asking why `istringstream::operator>>(double&)` generated a different value to `strtod`

Comment: oh, I focused on the `//this fails`

Comment: This test assumes that you want to measure relative error. I think it really depends on what the values represent and how the value are computed. There is no general answer.

Comment: @curiousguy: That's exactly the reason that the isEqual function does not define `epsilon`.  `epsilon` depends on where the numbers came from.